# Get user's AD groups AND subgroups using C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am using the following code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net) to retrieve a user's AD groups:

```
protected ArrayList GetADGroups()
{
    ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();

    foreach (IdentityReference group in HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
    {
        groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
    }

    return groups;
}
```

This works great to find top-level groups, however, it does not seem to retrieve any nested groups.

How do I do that?

Comment: Call a `GetGroupsFromGroup()` function against each top-level group you retrieve?

Comment: What about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3159424

Comment: There's also some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19405566

Comment: See also the Related sidebar to the right. ---->